# Jenkins Workflow Error When Accessing Variable Inside a Closure

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm using some groovy inside a Jenkins Workflow script that includes a closure.

```
def newMarkup = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
   mkp.yield(xml)
}.toString()
```

As I understand it `mkp` should be a variable made available inside closures when using `StreamMarkupBuilder`, however when I try and run this I get the error,

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: mkp for class: WorkflowScript
```

So my question is why doesn't Jenkins recognise that `mkp` is a property of the `StreamMarkupBuilder` class and not the workflow script?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in `groovy-cps`. Try encapsulating your logic inside a method marked with the `@NonCPS` annotation. If it starts working, then `groovy-cps` is to blame, and you can file a bug in the Jenkins JIRA in the `workflow-plugin` component with steps to reproduce, although I suspect even with the `MissingPropertyException` fixed the code would still not run due to [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481).

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.